# What is the difference of the words πόρνος (pornos) alongside μοιχός (moichos) in Hebrews 13:4 compared to πορνείας (porneias) in 1 Thess 4:3?

Tags: greek, translation-philosophy, sin, definition, etymology

**Q: What is the difference of the words **πόρνος (pornos)** alongside
**μοιχός (moichos)** in Hebrews 13:4 compared to **πορνείας (porneias)** in 1 Thess 4:3?**

Texts to compare:

> “Marriage is honorable among all, and the bed undefiled; but
> fornicators and adulterers God will judge.” ‭‭Hebrews‬ ‭13:4‬

> “For this is the will of God, your sanctification: that you should
> abstain from sexual immorality;” ‭‭I Thessalonians‬ ‭4:3‬ ‭

**NOTE:** ‭Older translations will say “that you should abstain from fornication, but πορνείας (porneias) is more broad, no?

Wouldn’t πορνείας (porneias) also imply abstaining not just from fornication but also imply to abstain from μοιχός (moichos) in 1 Thess 4:3?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the lexical meanings of these three words from BDAG:

**πορνεία (porneia)**

1. **unlawful sexual intercourse, *prostitution, unchastity, fornication***, eg, 1 Cor 5:1ab, 2 Cor 12:21, Gal 5:19, Eph 5:3, Rom 1:29, Col 3:5, 1 Cor 7:2, etc.
2. **participation in prohibited degrees of marriage, *fornication***, eg, Matt 5:32, 19:9, etc
3. **immorality of a transcendent nature, *fornication***, in imagery of polytheistic cult in the mystic city of Babylon which appears in Revelation as a prostitute with an international clientele.  From the time of Hosea the relationship between God and his people was regarded as a marriage bond. ..., eg, 2:21, 19:2, 9:21, etc.

**πόρνος (pornos)**

1. **one who practices sexual immorality, *fornicator***, eg, 1 Cor 5:9, 11, Heb 12:16, Rev 17:5, 1 Cor 5;10, Eph 5:5, 1 Tim 1:10, etc
2. **a political entity hostile to God, *fornicator***, Rev 17:5.

**μοιχός (moichos)**

1. **one who unfaithful to a spouse, *adulterer***, in the singular the referent is male, but in a generic contexts females may be included, eg, Heb 13:4, Luke 18:11, 1 Cor 6:9.
2. **one who is unfaithful to God, *adulterer***, eg, James 4:4, etc.

It is immediately apparent that the meanings of the first two overlap with the third.  That is, a person who is an adulterer (μοιχός) is also a fornicator (πόρνος).  I assume that when both are listed such as in Heb 13:4, it is remove any doubt about the fact that all such sinners are included.